# Using ADO.NET Entity Data Model, how do I pass (or set) the connection string password?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, ado.net

I am working with the ADO.NET Entity Data Model for this side project I am working on. Typically I would include the whole connection string (user and password) inside the web.config, but I was feeling frisky this morning so I decided to exclude the password from the connection string. Unfortunately for me, I cannot seem to figure out how to pass or set the password before I manipulate the database, and all the searching I've done so far have not yielded any fruitful results. All I have currently are a couple of lines that add a new record:

```
_entities.AddToUploadSet(uploadFile);
_entities.SaveChanges();
```

I see there is a `ConnectionString` property inside of `_entities.Connection`, but I failed to find anything useful like a password property.

Can anyone help me out? Thanks!

## edit

For clarification, this screenshot shows the step where I can choose whether or not to include the password in the web.config file:

[image]

So as you can see, I need to set it in my application code as the prompt suggests.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [connection string builder](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb738533.aspx).

Comment: Is that basically what I did below?

Comment: Well, you kind of wrote your own, but yes. :)

Comment: Yes, that is what I meant hehe. Good to know there is something built in that can do what I did. I will check it out, thanks for the link!

Answer (score 1):

Well, I did some digging around and duct-taped this solution together:

```
private static string CreateNewConnectionString(string connectionName, string password)
{
    var config = System.Web.Configuration.WebConfigurationManager.OpenWebConfiguration("~").ConnectionStrings.ConnectionStrings[connectionName];
    var split = config.ConnectionString.Split(Convert.ToChar(";"));
    var sb = new System.Text.StringBuilder();

    for (var i = 0; i <= (split.Length - 1); i++)
    {
        if (split[i].ToLower().Contains("user id"))
        {
            split[i] += ";Password=" + password;
        }

        if (i < (split.Length - 1))
        {
            sb.AppendFormat("{0};", split[i]);
        }
        else
        {
            sb.Append(split[i]);
        }
    }
    return sb.ToString();
}
```

Granted it is not the prettiest method, but it gets the job done. I pass it a connection string name and a password, and it returns an updated connection string with the password. This is how I implemented it:

```
_entities = new UploadEntity(CreateNewConnectionString("UploadEntity", "[removed]"));
_entities.AddToUploadSet(uploadFile);
_entities.SaveChanges();
```

Answer (score 0):

Inside your web.config there will be an entry similar to this:

```
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="HelpEntities" connectionString="metadata=res://*/Models.HelpModel.HelpModel.csdl|res://*/Models.HelpModel.HelpModel.ssdl|res://*/Models.HelpModel.HelpModel.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;Data Source=(local);Initial Catalog=XXX;Integrated Security=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True&quot;"
      providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
  </connectionStrings>
```

The above example uses integrated security but it is possible to use username and password instead.